# Exact match in type but Java compiler won't compile for List<type>?

Tags: java, generics

```
private ResourceAssembler<? extends BasedEntity> resourceAssembler;
List<? extends BasedEntity> bases = userRepository.findAll();
return resourceAssembler.toResources(bases, User.class);  //<-----compile error
```

Compile error

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<? extends BasedEntity>', required: 'java.util.List<? extends BasedEntity>'
```

Method signature

```
public class ResourceAssembler<T extends BasedEntity> {
    public Resources<Resource<T>> toResources(List<T> list, Class entityClass) {}
}
```

What's going on?

---

Minimal code example which can be copied and pasted into an empty project.

```
class Main {

    ResourceAssembler<? extends BasedEntity> resourceAssembler;
    List<? extends BasedEntity> bases;

    void test() {
        resourceAssembler.toResources(bases);
        //         the error is here: ^~~~~
    }

}

class BasedEntity {}

class ResourceAssembler<T extends BasedEntity> {
    void toResources(List<T> list) {}
}
```

Comment: What does the declaration line of the method `ResourceAssember.toResources(...)` look like?

Comment: No I do not, only one class

Comment: Both occurrences of `? extends BasedEntity` refer to an unknown type. Both types are assignable to `BasedEntity`, but there is no guaranty that both refer to the same type. To declare that it is the same, add a type variable to a surrounding entity and use that, e.g. `class Main<T extends BasedEntity>` and within the class `ResourceAssembler<T> resourceAssembler;` and `List<T> bases;`